# Using PERFORM in recursive query function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.5

I have a recursive query which I want to use in PostgreSQL function, and it should return a Boolean value.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION store.is_item(object1 VARCHAR(40), object2 VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
   WITH RECURSIVE externals AS (
   SELECT object_id, used_id
   FROM store.obj_depend
   WHERE external = true
   ), history AS (
   SELECT content_id AS id
   FROM store.minfos
   WHERE id= $2
   UNION
   SELECT externals.used_id
   FROM externals
   INNER JOIN history ON history.id = externals.object_id
   ),
   PERFORM (SELECT c.id FROM store.cinfo AS c WHERE c.id = $1 INNER JOIN history 
   ON c.id = history.id);
   RETURN FOUND;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try this it gives a`syntax error at or near SELECT` error.

Answer (score 0):

The `PERFORM` is plpgsql statement and cannot be used inside any SQL command.

You can use `PERFORM` like proposed @klin, but then CTE is used inside a subquery, and subquery returns one row every time. Then a `FOUND` variable should be every time true.

In this case is better to use auxiliary variable as targer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION store.is_item(object1 VARCHAR(40), object2 VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
  WITH RECURSIVE 
    externals AS (SELECT object_id, used_id
                    FROM store.obj_depend
                   WHERE external = true)
    history AS (SELECT content_id AS id
                  FROM store.minfos
                 WHERE id = object2
                UNION
                SELECT externals.used_id
                  FROM externals
                       INNER JOIN history ON history.id = externals.object_id)
  SELECT c.id
    FROM store.cinfo AS c 
         INNER JOIN history ON c.id = history.id
   WHERE c.id = $1 
    INTO r;
  RETURN FOUND;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```